# Hibernate entity property is `null` if it is not initialized with `Hibernate.unproxy`

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin

I have entity object with `type` propery is `null`(it is not null in db). When I call `Hibernate.unproxy` on entity object - and look at uproxied object `type` propery - it is not null. This entity is inherited from other entity(I mention it because I haven't seen this behaviour with not inherited entities).

Here is entities kotlin code:

```
open class HealthValue {

    @get:Id
    open var id: UUID? = null   
    @get:ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    open var healthValueType: HealthValueType? = null

}

class ObservedHealthValue : HealthValue() {

}

open class HealthValueType {

    @get:Id
    open var id: UUID? = null
    @get:Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @get:Column(nullable = false)
    var type: ObservationType? = null

}

class SelectionValueType : HealthValueType() {

}
```

Here is snippet with bug demo:

```
@Transactional
fun method(id: UUID) {
  val healthValue= entityManager.find(ObservedHealthValue::class.java, id)
  val type1 = healthValue.healthValueType!!.type // this value is null
  val type2 = Hibernate.unproxy(healthValue.healthValueType!!).type // this is not null
}
```

This behaviour looks strange, not sure using `Hibernate.unproxy` is correct approach. Do you have any ideas why it happens, how this can be fixed?

My hibernate version is: 5.3.7.Final(It comes from gradle dependecy `compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")` with enabled `'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.0.RELEASE'` plugin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found reson - it is because `type` field was not `open`. In kotlin all field are `final` by default so you need to specify them as `open`. So this way it worked:

```
open class HealthValueType {
    @get:Id
    open var id: UUID? = null
    @get:Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @get:Column(nullable = false)
    open var type: ObservationType? = null
}
```

But, better solution is using [kotlin-allopen](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html) plugin.